# How to get difference in hour working with Datetime

Tags: excel, vba

I have following data in excel:

```
category       time1                  time2
High           01/03/2021 14:15:00    01/03/2021 15:00:00
High           01/03/2021 17:25:00    01/03/2021 17:35:05
High           01/03/2021 14:15:00    01/03/2021 15:55:09
```

I want to get time difference between `time2` - `time1` in hours. For example, required data.

```
category       time1                  time2                  Difference
High           01/03/2021 14:15:00    01/03/2021 15:00:00    1
High           01/03/2021 17:25:00    01/03/2021 18:25:05    1
High           01/03/2021 14:15:00    01/03/2021 15:45:09    0.5
```

I have tried `=text(time2-time1,"h")` but it gives me 0 where the difference is < 1 hour.

Comment: Excel stores date/time as days and fractions of a day.  So just subtract one from the other -- Result will be in fractions of a day.  For decimal hours you would then multiply by 24.

Comment: `=(time2-tim1) * 24`

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is correct.  It is returning `0` for your first two entries because those have less than one hour difference.  If you changed your formula to

```
=text(c2-b2,"h:mm")
```

you would get a non-zero result.

If you do not want the difference in hours expressed as a date/time, please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Hour 1:00 is 1/24 in number. 1 day is 1 in number.
One hour is 1/24 of a day.

Differenc column foramt

```
0.0_
```

formula as below

```
= (time2-time1) *24
```